# What was the Western involvement in Finland's deal with the Soviets to be neutral?

Tags: finland, nato

There was being some comment about this from Yanis Varoufakis (see below). But some people are challenging if Varoufakis is making any sense...so I don't know the facts. How much was the West involved in this neutrality for Finland? Was there a summit and was the West involved in the summit? Was there being a handshakes between the US and Soviet leader concerning Finnish neutrality?

https://www.democracynow.org/2022/3/25/yanis_varoufakis_biden_give_putin_exit

> YANIS VAROUFAKIS: Well, let’s take Finland, shall we? Finland had a war with Russia, with the Soviets. There was a stalemate, very much like what we have now in Ukraine. And the result was neutrality. There was an agreement between Washington, on the one hand, and Moscow, on the other, that Moscow would not interfere with Finland, it would not invade, it would take its troops out, and Finland would be allowed to live an independent, Western, democratic lifestyle, as long as it doesn’t join NATO and it doesn’t host American or European armies in its territory. The result was a wonderful state, a country, you know, that in every ranking outranks your country, the United States, my country, Greece, when it comes to education, to democracy, to technological innovation. Remember Nokia and all the great companies that came out of Finland. Finland is a success story. Neutrality allowed Finland to have democracy, independence and success and shared prosperity, a social democratic country, similarly with Sweden, similarly with Austria. So it’s a well-tested and well-tried-out model.
>
> The reason that Ukraine has not had the same opportunity so far — because some people will say that — it’s been said that they gave up their nuclear weapons, they were not in NATO, therefore they were neutral, and nevertheless they suffered incursions and now this invasion by Mr. Putin. Well, it wasn’t the same. What Ukraine lacks is a summit, a summit between the American president and the Russian president, a summit involving the government of the United States and the government of Russia. This is what Finland had, what Austria had. The two blocs, NATO and the Warsaw Pact, represented by the president of the Soviet Union, or the general secretary of Communist Party then, and the American president, or a series of American presidents, they agreed — they shook hands — that Finland, Sweden, Austria will be left alone, under conditions of neutrality, to prosper democratically and to be part of the West without being part of NATO.

Comment: Are you aware of the **series** of conferences during WWII, coordinating the conduct of the war and also the war aims?

Comment: [Yanis Varoufakis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democracy_in_Europe_Movement_2025) is well known (by his own account) for being an expert in everything. Unfortunately his actual achievements in the areas, where he considers himself an expert, are less well known. I would suggest looking for reliable sources for the background of the Soviet/Finnish relationship. A good starting point would be [Finlandization - Paasikivi doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finlandization#Paasikivi_doctrine).

Comment: The situation is considerably different from 1945-48. Russia's combination of aggressiveness, inefficiency and unpredictability has set Sweden and Finland to [preparing to apply for NATO membership](https://www.politico.eu/article/sweden-finland-collect-nato-assurances-as-application-decision-looms/).

Comment: Russia has disavowed their guarantees made in (1997) for the security and integrity of Ukraine. There was an agreement, Russia reneged. Hence why Finland is considering its options for itself. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian%E2%80%93Ukrainian_Friendship_Treaty

Comment: It's oversimplified, at best. Note, for instance, that the Winter War was over and done with a year before the US finally entered WW II. It was not an active part of those negotiations,much less a superpower the USSR could deal with. During the Cold War era?  It's impossible to believe the subject of Finland never came up, but the US was focused on stopping Soviet expansion and a free but neutral Finland would have been just fine.

Comment: Already the opening passage "Finland had a war with Russia, with the Soviets. There was a stalemate... And the result was neutrality" is quite wrong. I do not think he knows what he is talking about. He conflates the "Winter War" of 1939-40 and the "Continuation War."  Neither one resulted in a stalemate. Finnish neutrality was the (eventual) result of its defeat in the Continuation War. In fact, in the immediate aftermath of WWII, Finland was effectively a Soviet satellite, as USSR established a military base near Helsinki, which was returned to Finland only in 1955.

Comment: Also would point out that the USSR would have had 0 need to negotiate with the USA on this matter. And further that *official* agreements with the USA have to be ratified by Congress. Anything else is at best a handshake agreement with the current POTUS, who will be gone in at most 8 years.

Comment: @T.E.D. The USA did not sign or ratify the [1947 Paris Peace Treaty with Finland](https://digital-commons.usnwc.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2177&context=ils) because the two countries had not been at war.  But the UK, Australia, Canada, India, New Zealand and South Africa had declared war on Finland during the Continuation War and so did sign and ratify.  Meanwhile the USA did sign and ratify the similar [1947 Paris Peace Treaty with Bulgaria](https://avalon.law.yale.edu/20th_century/usmu012.asp) - so similar that several of the articles were identical in both treaties

Comment: The bottom line is that Varoufakis completely misrepresented the history. You can start by reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Finland#Neutrality_in_Cold_War) Wikipedia article on Finnish neutrality during the Cold War.

Comment: is there any way i can be getting an engagement with each of these ideas?? these are being the key ideas as far as I can be telling: How much was the West involved in this neutrality for Finland? Was there a summit and was the West involved in the summit? Was there being a handshakes between the US and Soviet leader concerning Finnish neutrality?

Comment: @NeedGrammarHelp Not involved at all ; No and No ; No.

Answer (score 9):

The comparison between Ukraine and Finland is an attempt to shift the blame for the current war from Russia to the West. Alas, there are plenty of "useful idiots" in the West who are promoting this narrative.

In short, there is nothing in common.

## Finland

#### History

Finns are not Slavs.  Their languages are completely different.

Finland was incorporated into Russia only in [1809](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Duchy_of_Finland) and enjoyed significant autonomy until [its independence in 1917](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_of_Finland), despite [policy of Russification of Finland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russification_of_Finland).

#### 1940-ies

Stalin [tried to conquer Finland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winter_War) and saw that the cost will be too high (guerrilla war) while the value is low (little industry).
So he settled for some (developed) land and military bases - getting all the benefits of conquest without the cost of an insurgency and bad PR with the West.

## Ukraine

Ukraine is a slavic country, so Russians can claim it to be theirs with some credibility among the credulous.

Ukraine has been the [battlefield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Ukraine) between Poland, Turkey and Russia for centuries, eventually landing in the Russian hands.

Ukraine is heterogeneous - East speaks mostly Russian, West speaks a version of Ukrainian unintelligible to the rest - *however*, **everyone** understands and can speak the "*Kiev TV Ukrainian*" (cf. "BBC English").

This, the benefits (to *Russia*, ***not*** *Ukraine*!) of *peaceful* incorporation of Ukraine into Russia are immense.

Russia miscalculated the *costs* of the invasion. It might well be that this war will help Ukraine overcome the internal divisions, but this is no longer history...

## The bottom line

The West did nothing to save Finland - it fought and won its independence by demonstrating that the occupation cost will be too high. (actually, not quite true, IIRC, US did lobby on behalf of Finland - but that was inconsequential compared to the Finnish war effort).

The West could do nothing to prevent Russian aggression in Ukraine, and the only thing it can do now is keep arming and feeding Ukraine - and *not* listening to Russian shills.